# App crash when setBackButtonBackgroundImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying using the code below to set the appearance of UINavigationBar globally:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_daohang"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_fanhui_1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I have successed to set the barStyle and the backGroundImage, but when I set the appearance of backButtonBack (the third line). The app crash and I get the error as below :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIAppearance     setBackButtonBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dd7ea00'
```

How to correctly set the appearance of backButtonBack globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:` belongs to `UIBarButtonItem`.

Use:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_fanhui_1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```